# NSAppleScript to highlight text in any Mac app with given NSRange

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsapplescript

I am trying to highlight text in any Mac app through may custom Mac app, by making use of NSAppleScript. I have tried below code but it doesn't work.

```
NSAppleScript* scriptObject = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\
tell application \"%@\"\n\
activate\n\
end tell\n\
tell application \"%@\"\n\
set theRange to create range start %ld end %ld\n\
set highlight color index of theRange to %@\n\
end tell\n\
",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"AppName"],[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"AppName"],(unsigned long)range.location, (unsigned long)(range.location+range.length),@"yellow"]];
```

But I am getting below error :

```
NSAppleScriptErrorBriefMessage = "Expected end of line but found identifier.";
    NSAppleScriptErrorMessage = "Expected end of line but found identifier.";
    NSAppleScriptErrorNumber = "-2741";
    NSAppleScriptErrorRange = "NSRange: {459, 5}";
```

Is there any other way I can do this? any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Tip: Test the script string in Script Editor.

Comment: @Willeke, it doesn't work in Script Editor too. Is there anyway I can check which keywords works fine in appleScript for which application. I have got a  reference link [https://iworkautomation.com/pages/body-text-basics.html] in which there is an example to change text color. but setting background color / selection of text doesn't work.

Comment: Open the dictionary of the application in Script Editor.

Answer (score 2):

This cannot work for all applications because the application specified in `NSUserDefaults` must have an AppleScript dictionary and this dictionary must contain the commands, properties and classes.

Many applications aren't scriptable at all and almost all applications don't understand `create range` and `highlight color index`.

The error is a compiling error.

---

And from the ObjC perspective never use `valueForKey:` with `NSUserDefaults` unless you can explain why KVC is explicitly needed in this case. There is `stringForKey:` and for `id` objects `objectForKey:`

Comment: 1. The `tell application` argument is a literal at compile time of the AppleScript.

Comment: @Willeke Right, thanks, I was confused by the placeholders. I clarified the answer.